# Floating button setOnClickListener not gets called in Android

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener, floating-action-button

I want to integrate movable floating button same like **"WhatsApp"** Application When open, it displays *hike floating button* with motion. And also working click event.

I used with default `OnTouch` event it's working but I can't apply Click event on floating button. How can I apply both **Click and touch event** ?

Thanks in advance!

**home.xml**

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_parent_floating"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/rl_floating_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtCartCount"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fab"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fab"
                android:background="@drawable/cart_gold_circle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="2"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="8sp" />

            <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_floating_cart"
                fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/header_color_red"
                fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/gold_color" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Home.java**

```
     mFloatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            mRrootLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.rl_floating_button);
            rl_floating_button = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_floating_button);
            rl_parent_floating = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_parent_floating);
mFloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent mIntent = new Intent(mActivity, Cart.class);
                startActivity(mIntent);
            }
        });

            mFloatingActionButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

                    final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
                    final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();

                    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                            view.getLayoutParams();

                            _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                            _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view
                                    .getLayoutParams();
                            layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                            layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
                            layoutParams.rightMargin = 0;
                            layoutParams.bottomMargin = 0;
                            view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                            break;
                    }
                    mRrootLayout.invalidate();
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting in it

Comment: Touch event is working and I can drag and drop floating button but I want to change Activity when click on it. It's not working.

Comment: is your App crashing or what?

Comment: And also when I use this piece of code

<RelativeLayout xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/rl_floating_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

Then It moves only bottom right side not whole screen.

Comment: No. I can't get any error or anything but click event is not working

Comment: Use `gestureDetector` to detect single tap and check on `OnTouchListener` to handle events. check my answer

Comment: Okay. Let me try this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SimpleOnGestureListener & GestureDetector` class to get single tap on screen instead of using Interface `setOnclickListner` as it may not work with `ontouchListner`

```
private class SingleTapDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener{
    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {

        return true;
    }

}
```

and then in `onCreate` method initialize `GestureDetector` like this

```
gestureDetector=new GestureDetector(this,new SingleTapDetector());
```

Now, check in `OnTouchListener` of floating bubble , if single tap is detected on floating button

**Code**

```
mFloatingActionButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
 @Override
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
 if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
  // code for single tap or onclick

  // pass your intent here
  } else {

  switch(event.getAction()){
  //  code for move and drag

  // handle your MotionEvents here
  }
     return true;
            }
        });
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot It's work.  when I use this piece of code 
<RelativeLayout xmlns:fab="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"; android:id="@+id/rl_floating_button" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_margin="10dp"> Then It moves only bottom right side not whole screen.

Comment: let me clear what you want to make floating bubble move anywhere on screen ?

Comment: By default I want Floating Button at Bottom|Right so, I used android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  at Relative layout But It cause move only bottom right not whole screen

Comment: I think you should use LinearLayout instead of relativelayout and set layout_grativity to right | bottom.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101278/discussion-between-krishna-vrinsoft-and-kapil-rajput).